# Debugging client certificate problems

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I am trying to configure an Apache install to accept client certificates. When I work with self-signed certificate, unknown to Apache and using Firefox, it works when `SSLVerifyClient` set to `optional_no_ca`.

However, we also try to connect from WebMethods SAP, and it gives an error (the message says "Server certicate rejected by chain verifier."), but I cannot see what is going on in my Apache install.

Is there a way to see what Apache is receiving / sending from this client? My logs are all empty for this IP address.

I got some more logging by putting the `LogLevel` to `debug`. This is the message I get now:

> [Fri Mar 27 14:30:19.030334 2015] [ssl:info] [pid 2154] SSL Library Error: error:14094412:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate (SSL alert number 42) -- Subject CN in certificate not server name or identical to CA!?

What does that mean, and does the client certificate need to have the server CN in it?

Comment: Try with https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DebuggingSSLProblems

Comment: @FedericoSierra thanks, but that page doesn't talk about client certificates.

Comment: Start with https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DebuggingSSLProblems#Enable_SSL_logging

Comment: @FedericoSierra I did that, found out it is SSL Alert 42.

Comment: This mean the Common Name in the certificate is not the same as the
ServerName - e.g. the certificate belongs to www.123.com
but you are using it in a server whose URL is www.abc.com. This makes
the client think your site is impersonating another site and so throws a warning. Where did you get the cert? Is it self-signed? If so, make a new one with the correct server name.

Comment: @FedericoSierra the strange thing is, this is a *client certificate* that is having this problem. The "normal" SSL operation works perfectly. Only when this particular client connects, I get this problem.